# Load all image files from a mobile storage using AIR for Android

Tags: android, image, actionscript-3, air, load

I am developing an Android app using AIR 24. I want to load all image files on the android device and later display in my app. What is the way to browse all image files on the android device? Can you please give me a code sample? Thanks!

Comment: this is not a code providing site. You should show what you tried so far and we'll try to help you out

Comment: The **File** class provides you with everything you need to read the local device filesystem structure: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html